# Foreign key constraints are incompatible?

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to get my migrations to work after reworking some of the table logic and I'm running into an issue when migrating. Something to do with a constraint conflict.

When running `php artisan migrate:fresh` it shows this,

```
In Connection.php line 665:

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'cache_id' and referenced column 'id' in
   foreign key constraint 'cache_connections_cache_id_foreign' are incompatible. (SQL: alter table
   `cache_connections` add constraint `cache_connections_cache_id_foreign` foreign key (`cache_id`
  ) references `cache` (`id`))


In Connection.php line 459:

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'cache_id' and referenced column 'id' in
   foreign key constraint 'cache_connections_cache_id_foreign' are incompatible.
```

Migrations:

```
Schema::create('cache', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('item')->unique();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('picture');
    $table->string('description');
    $table->unsignedInteger('connection_count');
    $table->boolean('is_private');
    $table->json('additional_data')->nullable();
    $table->string('type_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('cache_connections', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigInteger('cache_id');
    $table->string('connection');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('cache_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('cache')
    ;
});
```

Comment: `bigIncrements()` is unsigned so `cache_id` should probably be `unsignedBigInteger` (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations#creating-columns)

Answer (score 4):

It could be due to the fact that `bigIncrements()` uses `unsignedBigInteger()`, not `bigInteger()`.  Try updating your `cache_connections` migration to use the unsigned method.

**vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php**

```php
    /**
     * Create a new auto-incrementing big integer (8-byte) column on the table.
     *
     * @param  string  $column
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Schema\ColumnDefinition
     */
    public function bigIncrements($column)
    {
        return $this->unsignedBigInteger($column, true);
    }
```